# Any way to both pass form data and fun a fetch command with the same button press?

Tags: javascript, forms, async-await, fetch-api

I might be going about this entirely the wrong way, but I'm working off of whatever tutorials I can find and am still getting acquainted with javascript, so I may very well have missed something obvious. I've tried everything I can think of and I'm completely out of ideas. I will detail what I've tried below. First, the problem:

I have a form, and I am trying to:

1. Pass the contents of the form to a php script, which does some processing and then amends it to an html file, `feed.html`, then
2. update a div to reflect the contents of `feed.html`, without having to completely refresh the page.

Here is the form and the div I want to update:

```html
<div id="feed"></div>

<form onsubmit="return sendData()" id="tincan">
  <textarea id="shoutAperture" name="shoutAperture"></textarea>
  <!--<input type="submit" id="shout" name="shout" value="SHOUT">-->
  <button id="shout" name="shout">SHOUT</button>
</form>
```

(I have also tried it with `<input type="submit">` instead of a button in case that made any difference, thus the commented-out code.)

Here are the scripts I have, which so far just collect the contents of the textarea and pass them to shout.php:

```js
async function summonFeed() {
  let file = "feed.html";
  let summons = await fetch(file);
  let feed = await summons.text();
  document.getElementById("feed").innerHTML = feed;
}
summonFeed();

function sendData() {
  let data = new FormData(document.getElementById("tincan"));
  fetch("shout.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body: data,
  });
  return false;
}
```

It successfully passes the form data to my php script and, from there, to `feed.html`, and when there is text in the `feed.html` file it does successfully show up on page load, but I can't get it to refresh dynamically. So far, no matter what I've tried, I have only been able to get the "feed" div to update upon hard refreshing the page (control-clicking the refresh button in Firefox; it does nothing when I simply click refresh). I have tried:

- calling multiple functions in `form onsubmit` (I tried separating them with `&`, `&&`, `,`, and `;` as indicated by various decade-old forum threads). This usually made it update the url in the address bar instead of actually passing my data to the php script.
- adding a `.then` command to `function sendData ()` either calling the `summonFeed` script or just wholesale repeating all of its code. (Nothing happens.) (I admit I don't think I've fully grasped the mechanics of `.then`, despite my best efforts.)
- creating a third function which runs `sendData` and `summonFeed`, and calling that from the form instead of `sendData`. (Nothing happens, or it just updates the url instead of passing the data to my php file.)
- creating a separate onClick function that just runs `summonFeed` again when the button is pressed (It still calls the old version of the file from before the php script updated it; when I hard refresh the page the changes appear.)

I think that's all I tried, but I have been at this for hours and may have forgotten some things. Any suggestions would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: Try `let file = "feed.html?v=" + Math.random();`

Comment: Where exactly are you calling `summonFeed` though?

Comment: Why does the PHP script update the file instead of just returning the data?

Comment: The reason you're getting the old version of the HTML is because of caching. So either configure cache control headers on the server, or use a cache-buster in the URL.

Comment: If you fix that, the `.then(summonFeed)` solution should work.

Comment: Thank you Unmitigated, your and Shirofuji's solution worked! Barmar, the reason is that I want to use the file for something else afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Unmitigated's comment about appending a query parameter to the filename to prevent it from caching in the browser. Have you tried the following:

```js
async function summonFeed() {
  let file = "feed.html?t=" + (new Date().getTime()); // append a query paramter for cache busting
  let summons = await fetch(file);
  let feed = await summons.text();
  document.getElementById("feed").innerHTML = feed;
}
summonFeed();

function sendData() {
  let data = new FormData(document.getElementById("tincan"));
  fetch("shout.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body: data,
  }).then(function () { // after the request has been sent
    summonFeed();       // call summonfeed to update the div with the new contents of feed.html
  })
  return false;
}
```